Jetpack derivedStateOf doesn't invoke when state change
I'm new to Jetpack. Currently, I have trouble with the derivedStateOf API. I expect that the derivedStateOf will be called when the email state changes, and then the bgColor will be changed to Red, but nothing happened
Please help me to explain the issue is, and how to fix it, thank you!!

@Composable
fun TestDerivedState() {
    Box (Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        var email by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        DerivedCompose(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 24.dp)
                .height(56.dp)
                .align(Alignment.Center),
            value = email,
            onClick = {
                email = it
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun DerivedCompose(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    value: String,
    onClick: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val bgColor by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            Timber.d("value: $value")
            if (value.isBlank()) Color.Red else Color.Green
        }
    }
    Button(
        onClick = {
            onClick(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        },
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            containerColor = bgColor
        ),
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Text(text = "test derived state, $value")
    }
}


What is it that you want to do exactly? Change the color of the button based on the value of the email string? If so, why are you using derivedStateOf for this?

derivedStateOf only updates when any State objects that were used in the calculation change. Since you only use value which is a simple String, the derived state will never change.
derivedStateOf is not what you need here. Instead you can use the mechanics of remember itself:
val bgColor = remember(value) { if (value.isBlank()) Color.Red else Color.Green }

By providing value as a parameter you effectively tell remember to only perform a recalculation if value changes.
That said, in this specific situation I would probably drop the remember alltogether and only do this:
val bgColor = if (value.isBlank()) Color.Red else Color.Green

It is simpler and doesn't occur the overhead of the remember mechanics, but it will execute the calculation on every recomposition now, not only when value changes.
Unless you expect this to be heavily recomposed (like as a part of an animation), the calculation is so simple1 that I wouldn't bother to remember the result.

1 The most costly part of the calculation is isBlank() which iterates over each character in value. This is very fast, but if you want it to be even faster then make sure there never are only blank characters in the string by applying trim() to it when you set the email:
onClick = {
    email = it.trim()
},

Now you can use value.isEmpty() instead of value.isBlank() which operates in constant time.

I have learned so much from your answer. Thank you!

I confirm it's not possible to change the color using derivedStateOf.
And also I think this is the best answer for your question, answer or go to the documentation
well you can always do this, derivedStateOf is heavy anyway.
hope this helpful
 Button(
        onClick = {
            onClick(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        },
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            containerColor = if (value.isBlank()) Color.Red else Color.Green
        ),
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Text(text = "test derived state, $value")
    }



This is working code
@Composable
fun TestDerivedState() {
Column (Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(12.dp)) {
    var email by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val bgColor by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (email.isBlank()) Color.Red else Color.Green
        }
    }
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = email,
        onValueChange = { email = it },
        label = { Text(text = "Email") },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(12.dp)
    )
    Button(
        onClick = {
            //onClick(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        },
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            containerColor = bgColor
        ),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(12.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = "test derived state, $email")
    }
 }
 }

